# React - props not being passed between files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have these three files: App, Main and Login. I am trying to pass username from Login to Main (and then to a few other files) but I'm getting undefined. 
In App I have these navigators:

```
const mainOptions = SwitchNavigator({
  main : Main,
  favPlaces : favPlaces,

})
const introStack = StackNavigator({
  loggingIn : LoggingIn,
  register : Register
})

const SwNavigator = SwitchNavigator({
  login : introStack,
  main : mainOptions

})
```

Login:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          credentials: {
            username: "",
            password:"",

          }
        }
        this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;
    }
      signIn(){ //when a button is clicked
          {....}
          this.navigate("main", {
                username: this.state.username,
              });
        }
  }
```

Main:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;
    this.params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
}
{...}
    render() {
    console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.username); //UNDEFINED
```

Comment: It looks like it should be `this.state.credentials.username` instead of `this.state.username`

Comment: Do you mean in signIn()? I changed it to this but I'm still getting "undefined is not an object".navigate("main", {
        params: {
        credentials: this.state.credentials.username,
        }
      });

Comment: Verify that `this.state.credentials` exists? Or _something_; do some `console.log` debugging

Comment: With these three logs it was only the first one (this.state.username) that actually printed it. credentials was password: "" and the same with username. Credentials.username was completely blank. console.log("username", this.state.username)
      console.log("credentials", this.state.credentials)
      console.log("credentials.username", this.state.credentials.username)

Comment: Strange... maybe the code somewhere else in the Login component isn't updating state properly? Otherwise I'm not sure what else it could be

Comment: I don't understand it either. I am logging the user before navigating and passing it and I can see that it's clearly updated.